# Having trouble with using powermock and jbehaves

Tags: powermock, jbehave

I am using powermock in one of my jbehaves.
I am getting the following error:

```java
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.193 sec <<< FAILURE!
run(com.cerner.surginet.picklist.rest.AreaStory)  Time elapsed: 0.94 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound: Story path 'area.story' not found by class loader org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader@31a5c39e
    at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.resourceAsStream(LoadFromClasspath.java:44)
    at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.loadResourceAsText(LoadFromClasspath.java:29)
    at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.loadStoryAsText(LoadFromClasspath.java:38)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.storyOfPath(StoryRunner.java:191)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.storyOfPath(StoryManager.java:49)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runningStoriesAsPaths(StoryManager.java:101)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runStories(StoryManager.java:78)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:202)
    at org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStory.run(JUnitStory.java:24)
```

I have tried to turn off the MockClassLoader by doing the following:

```java
@PowerMockIgnore({
"javax.net.ssl.*",
"javax.management.*",
"jdk.internal.reflect.*,org.jbehave.core.io.*,org.jbehave.*,org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.*,org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.*"
})
```

However, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think misunderstood what the error was. The problem was it did not look in the correct place for the story files. It did not look in the correct directory.